# Quickly assign values between DataFrame based on multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One, named population has two columns randomly ordered positions. The other, named keyFrame, has two columns of ordered keys and a column of attributes  (`'attr'`) associated with the pair of keys.

I use the below code to:

1. Create an empty column in population.
2. Iterate over each row in *keyFrame* (the iterable dataframe is not being altered).
3. Assign the rows `'attr'` value to populations `'assignment'` where either `position1 == key1 & position2 == key2` OR where `position1 == key2 & position2 == key1`.

This works perfectly, but is *extremely* slow in my actual code. the population dataframe is >500k rows in actuality and the keyFrame dataframe has >1500 values.

**Question: Is there a way to assign the `'attr'` values from keyFrame to population  where the keys match (interchangeably) all at once?**

```
# Sample code for you to test! Thank you!    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

population = pd.DataFrame(data={'position1': [1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 8, 16],
                                'position2': [5, 1, 15, 9, 17, 1, 2, 1, 1]})
keyFrame = pd.DataFrame(data={'key1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                              'key2': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
                              'attr': [0.79, 0.65, 0.99, 0.03, 0.58, 0.19, 0.53,
                                       0.76, 0.49, 0.46, 0.25, 0.11, 0.22, 0.38, 0.94]})

population['assignment'] = np.NaN  # Step 1
for index, row in keyFrame.iterrows():  # Step 2
    # Step 3
    population['assignment'].loc[((population['position1'] == row['key1']) & (
                population['position2'] == row['key2'])) | (
                (population['position1'] == row['key2']) & (
                population['position2'] == row['key1']))] = row['attr']
```

P.S. I am aware many questions exist that are similar to this, but they either don't fully match my use case or they don't solve the issue in a more efficient manner.

**FINAL: Thanks to all the great suggestions! These all worked and were much faster than my original implementation!!**

In terms of speed the results were as follows:

1. BeRT2me's method: 18.45s
2. Jānis Š's method: 21.34s
3. ouroboros1's method: 26.96s

**I must hazard for anyone who comes across these solutions though, they are sensitive to index values. Make sure to reset all indices for the `population` and `keyFrame` dataframes.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Pretty much *Anything* will be more efficient than `iterrows`. DataFrames are not meant to be iterated over for tasks like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to merge both ways and then combine the results.

```
# smol var names make me happy.
p_df = population
k_df = keyFrame

df1 = p_df.merge(k_df, left_on=['position1', 'position2'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'])
df2 = p_df.merge(k_df, left_on=['position2', 'position1'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   position1  position2  key1  key2  attr
0          1          5     1     5  0.03
1          1         15     1    15  0.22
2          1          9     1     9  0.76
3          1         17     1    17  0.94
4          1          2     1     2  0.79
5          6          1     1     6  0.58
6          7          1     1     7  0.19
7          8          1     1     8  0.53
8         16          1     1    16  0.38
```

---

If we want to pre-sort things...

```
p_cols = ['position1', 'position2']
p_df[p_cols] = np.sort(p_df[p_cols], axis=1)

k_cols = ['key1', 'key2']
k_df[k_cols] = np.sort(k_df[k_cols], axis=1)

df = p_df.merge(k_df, left_on=['position1', 'position2'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'])
print(df)
```

(Same Output as above)

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

```
population['assignment'] = population[['position1','position2']]\
    .apply(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand')\
        .merge(keyFrame, left_on=[0,1], right_on=['key1','key2'], how='left')\
            ['attr']

   position1  position2  assignment
0          1          5        0.03
1          6          1        0.58
2          1         15        0.22
3          1          9        0.76
4          1         17        0.94
5          7          1        0.19
6          1          2        0.79
7          8          1        0.53
8         16          1        0.38
```

**Explanation**

- First, we use [`.apply(sorted, axis=1, result_type='expand')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to cols `position1, position2` to get two cols (default names: `[0,1]`) with the values sorted for each row. E.g. `[1,5], [1,6]` etc.
- Sorted, we can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `left_on=[0,1]` and `right_on=['key1','key2']`, select only `attr`, and assign it to a new column for the df `population`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this (almost the same as @ouroboros1 proposed):

```
population['key'] = [tuple(sorted([p1, p2])) for p1, p2 in zip(population.position1, population.position2)]
keyFrame['key'] = [tuple(sorted([k1, k2])) for k1, k2 in zip(keyFrame.key1, keyFrame.key2)]
population['assignment'] = population.merge(keyFrame[['key', 'attr']], on='key')['attr']
population.drop(columns=['key'], inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
   position1  position2  assignment
0          1          5        0.03
1          6          1        0.58
2          1         15        0.22
3          1          9        0.76
4          1         17        0.94
5          7          1        0.19
6          1          2        0.79
7          8          1        0.53
8         16          1        0.38
```